# Dapper TypeHandler.SetValue() not being called

Tags: c#, dapper

I am testing Dapper to load / persist objects to an Oracle database, and to manage Oracle's Guid storage I need a `SqlMapper.TypeHandler<Guid>`. When loading a Guid column from the database the Parse method is called, but when I attempt to execute an SQL statement using a Guid parameter I get the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled;  Message=Value does not fall
>   within the expected range.Source=Oracle.DataAccess.

In debug I can see that my handler's Parse() method is being called when loading my class from the database, but the SetValue() mdethod is not.

The code to reproduce the exception is below

---

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id     RAW (16) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                  name   VARCHAR2 (30) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO foo (id, name) VALUES (SYS_GUID (), 'Bar');

COMMIT;
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Dapper;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

namespace Program
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class GuidTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<Guid>
    {
        public override Guid Parse(object value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handling Parse of {0}", value);

            var inVal = (byte[])value;
            byte[] outVal = new byte[] { inVal[3], inVal[2], inVal[1], inVal[0], inVal[5], inVal[4], inVal[7], inVal[6], inVal[8], inVal[9], inVal[10], inVal[11], inVal[12], inVal[13], inVal[14], inVal[15] };
            return new Guid(outVal);
        }

        public override void SetValue(System.Data.IDbDataParameter parameter, Guid value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handling Setvalue of {0}", value);

            var inVal = value.ToByteArray();
            byte[] outVal = new byte[] { inVal[3], inVal[2], inVal[1], inVal[0], inVal[5], inVal[4], inVal[7], inVal[6], inVal[8], inVal[9], inVal[10], inVal[11], inVal[12], inVal[13], inVal[14], inVal[15] };
            parameter.Value = outVal;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler<Guid>(new GuidTypeHandler());
            var conn = new OracleConnection(Resources.ConnectionString);
            var def = new CommandDefinition("select id, name from foo");

            conn.Open();

            var foo = conn.Query<Foo>(def).First();
            Console.WriteLine(foo.Id + "; " + foo.Name);

            foo.Name = "New Bar";

            def = new CommandDefinition(
                "UPDATE foo SET name = :name WHERE id = :id",
                parameters: new { ID = foo.Id, NAME = foo.Name });

            var rows = conn.Execute(def);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} rows inserted", rows);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get this to work?  I am experiencing a similar issue when I try to pass an array of custom objects into a query (e.g., "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = ANY(:ids)", and typeof(:ids) == typeof(myType[]))

Comment: No luck, it might be worth reposting the query in the Dapper issues list on Github.

Answer (score 15):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this post with a similar problem, I found a solution to handling `Guid`s without the need for wrappers.

The problem in Dapper is the order in which Dapper searches for matching `DbType` and `TypeHandler` implementations. Dapper prefers "native" `DbType` for a `Guid` (in `SqlMapper#LookupDbType`). In order to make Dapper use your own implementation, you have to remove the default mapping in addition to adding your own `TypeHandler`:

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler<Guid>(new GuidTypeHandler());
SqlMapper.RemoveTypeMap(typeof(Guid));
SqlMapper.RemoveTypeMap(typeof(Guid?));
```

I currently use a `string`-based implementation when working with SQLite:

```
public class GuidAsStringHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<Guid>
{
    public override Guid Parse(object value)
    {
        return new Guid((string) value);
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, Guid value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I worked around this issue by writing a wrapper around the .NET Guid class. Not ideal since you end up with the wrapper in your DTO classes but it works.

The wrapper class:

```
public class OracleGuid
{
    private Guid dotNetGuid;

    public OracleGuid(Guid guid)
    {
        this.dotNetGuid = guid;
    }

    public OracleGuid(Byte[] byteArray)
    {
        this.dotNetGuid = new Guid(byteArray);

    }

    public Guid InternalGuid { get { return dotNetGuid; } }
}
```

The handler class:

```
public class OracleGuidHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<OracleGuid>
{
    public override OracleGuid Parse(object value)
    {
        return new OracleGuid((byte[]) value);
    }

    public override void SetValue(System.Data.IDbDataParameter parameter, OracleGuid value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value.InternalGuid.ToByteArray();
    }
}
```

A DTO class that makes use of the wrapper class:

```
public class FooDto
{
    public OracleGuid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Note I'm using RAW(16) to store these in Oracle, not the built in Oracle Guids.

**EDIT**
Looks like this may have been a bug and may have been fixed: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues/253. Doesn't look like it has made it into the NuGet package yet so I haven't tried it out yet.