# Dapper custom TypeHandler SetValue not being called?

Tags: c#, dapper, typehandler

So, I have an data type which contains some `List<string>`'s, and as I want to serialize these to Json inside the table column, I added a simple TypeHandler for `List<string>`:

```
class Foo : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<List<string>>
{
    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, List<string> value)
    {
        // never hit
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override List<string> Parse(object value)
    {
        var val = value as string;
        if (val != null)
        {
            var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(val);
            return list;
        }
        throw new Exception("unknown value?");

    }
}

SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler<List<string>>(new Foo());
```

I'm trying to update a record, but `SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand` doesn't seem to call the SetValue on the List (though when reading fields, the Parse is called correctly). Instead it errors out telling me I have an error in my sql near ',' - I've used the same SQL before, so I know it's fine. For the parameters, I'm passing the properties that are of type `List<string>` rather than serializing them at the point of setting parameter values. I've tried modifying the query, removing all params that are `List<string>` and it's works flawlessly. I've also removed all params except for one `List<string>` param and I still get the same error that my SQL is wrong near ','.

I've double checked that the data type in the command is indeed `List<string>` and not some other implementation of `ICollection<string>` so the `SetValue` should be called.

Maybe it's worth pointing out I'm using SQLite.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? I note [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568657/dapper-typehandler-setvalue-not-being-called) has no answer.

**Update**: I've done lots of digging and think I may have found a bug - though would like someone more knowledgeable to say so. I have a `List<string>` param called Foo with two string values, and `SetupCommand` is trying to bind Foo1 and Foo2 to the underlying cmd. I assume this is the internal handling of enumerable, but shouldn't my custom data type have higher priority?

After stepping through: here's the [problem](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper%20NET40/SqlMapper.cs#L888) - a simple swapping of the `trygetvalue` below this code, and all works as expected - my handling of the list supersedes the default `enumerable` handling. Fix?

Comment: The bug has now been fixed in Dapper.Net https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues/253

Comment: This is bug. not fixed yet.